# Questions relating to playing movies

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/317/22) asks how to play Region-2 DVDs in the USA.  Is this on-topic?

> Is there a way to see Zone 2 in the USA?

My immediate reaction is that it is clearly *not* on topic; but then I realized I don't know where else to send the question.  Superuser would be great, if he was asking how to play on a computer, but non-computer questions on this topic are off-topic there ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/223188/how-to-play-a-dvd-from-a-different-region-on-the-ps3)).

If/when a home theater site goes live, that would be the obvious place for such a question.

Do we want to allow such questions here?  Or is this site strictly about the movies themselves?

Comment: FYI: just because a question doesn't have a place elsewhere, doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed. So if its off-topic (and I believe it is) then it should be closed

Comment: @IvoFlipse: I agree with that.

Comment: Personally, I think this is off-topic.  I'll put this in an answer if you want people to vote on that.

Comment: @iandotkelly: Sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: Perhaps we should bundle this one (and similar discussions) [in the FAQ question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Comment: @IvoFlipse: IMO, we should hash out the fine points here, then when a consensus is reached, it would be appropriate to add that to the FAQ question.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not sure what other consensus you need. Ian has answered with 6+ 0- and no comments. If someone disagrees they should be down voting or commenting.

Comment: @Alonzo: At the time I made that comment, there were no answers here.

Comment: Understood, I should have checked the timestamps.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the purpose of this group is to discuss the content of movies, and not the formats themselves.

I believe asking questions about how technology affects the content of the movies would be on-topic (for example 3D is the most obvious recent innovation, but Sound and Color are earlier ones).

This question which is purely about a format related issue which has no bearing on the content of the movie would therefore be off topic.