# Is the question on projection frame rates on-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Is this question on-topic?

[Do contemporary cinemas really project at 25fps?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/762/do-contemporary-cinemas-really-project-at-25fps)

It has received 1 off-topic close vote already.  I am unsure whether that is correct or not, even if the question itself could be improved.

We closed a question early in the beta relating to [cost of Blu-Rays](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71/why-do-blu-rays-cost-more-than-dvds).  The argument was that it related to formats and marketing - not a movie.

My argument why we might keep this (and other similar 'technical' questions about formats) is that this has an impact on the viewing experience of movies, so may have an impact on the content - such as widescreen, color, sound to give some more concrete examples.

What should we do here?

Comment: I would like to add that even questions like [Evolution of aspect ratio](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53/evolution-of-aspect-ratio) have been closed siting off topic reasons but it is a question that relates to movie techniques.

Comment: @karthik - yes, as I see it refining scope is an ongoing process in the beta - we are not always going to be consistent whilst this is happening unfortunately.  Perhaps that question should be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I honestly have no problem with questions about cinemas as long as they stick to a general nature like this question or questions about moments in cinemas history (example being why do cinemas not show as much content as they used to with the answer relating to home TV in some way).

If questions start popping up regarding best seating practices or about prices, etc the those should be closed.

Answer (score -2):

I think this question should be off-topic for the same reason questions about DVD formats are off topic.

See [related meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/questions-relating-to-playing-movies)

Comment: And in that meta post, the only one to answer is the asker of this question, with his same views, making the reference almost irrelevant and a counter to your own argument.

Comment: @Shads0: Uhh... what are you talking about? That's not true. I asked the question, and someone else answered it.

Comment: @Flimzy - he is saying that I answered your question, making the same point that I make here - that I agreed with you that questions of marketing or cost of formats are off-topic, but that (IMHO) technical questions that impact the experience of movies should be on-topic